# How to renumber a theorem environment with mdframed package?

Tags: boxes, theorems, mdframed, books

I have the next document, which compiles fine.

I want to change the numbering of theorems according to the number of section or chapter (view image).

I wrote:

```
\newmdtheoremenv{theo}{Theorem}[section]
```

But I get error.

What should I change in the header?

Thanks in advance.

```
 \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}

 \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
 \usepackage{mathtools}

 \mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}
 \newrobustcmd\ExampleText{%
 An \textit{inhomogeneous linear} differential equation has the form
 \begin{align}
 L[v ] = f,
 \end{align}
 where $L$ is a linear differential operator, $v$ is
 the dependent variable, and $f$ is a given non-zero
 function of the independent variables alone.}

 \begin{document}

 \newcounter{theo}[section]
 \newenvironment{theo}[1][]{%
 \stepcounter{theo}%
 \ifstrempty{#1}%
 {\mdfsetup{%
 frametitle={%
 \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
 \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
 {\strut Theorem~\thetheo};}}
 }%
 {\mdfsetup{%
 frametitle={%
 \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
    \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
    {\strut Theorem~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
 }%
 \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
         linewidth=2pt,topline=true,
         frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
 \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
 }{\end{mdframed}}

 \begin{theo}[Inhomogeneous Linear]
 \ExampleText
 \end{theo}

 \begin{theo}
 \ExampleText
 \end{theo}

 \end{document}
```

[image: this is the output of my tex file]

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Writing Theorem 2.1 for the 1st theorem of section 2, or just resetting theorem numbering at each new section?

Comment: Either use `\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\thechapter.\arabic{theo}}` or `\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\thesection.\arabic{theo}}` together with `\refstepcounter` instead of just `\stepcounter`.

Comment: Werner thank you very much. I wrote 
    \renewcommand{\thetheo}{\thechapter.\arabic{theo}} }
just above 
    \ begin {theo} ..
and it worked perfectly :)

Comment: @Bernard Yes that's exactly what I want. But I solved thanks anyway.

Comment: @Werner I have one last question: How to write code latex in these comment boxes ?, these codes you left highlighted in gray. Thanks.

Comment: @mathsalomon: I converted my comment into an answer. If you're talking about formatting code inside comments, then you need to use backticks. See [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3150/5764).

Comment: @Werner OK Thanks. Excellent!! ``\latex``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use

```
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\thechapter.\arabic{theo}}% ...for chapter prefix
```

or

```
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{\thesection.\arabic{theo}}% ...for section prefix
```

together with `\refstepcounter` instead of just `\stepcounter`. This allows you to use `\label` and later `\ref`erence the theorem.